# Why does an x86 WiX installer on Windows Vista x64 not write keys to Wow6432Node in the registry?

Tags: windows-vista, wix, registry, x86, 64-bit

I have an installer that writes to `HKLM\Software\DroidExplorer\InstallPath`. On any x86 machine it writes just fine to the expected location, and on Windows XP x64 and Windows 7 x64 it also writes to the expected location, which is actually `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\DroidExplorer\InstallPath`.

Later on during the install, my bootstrapper, which is also x86, attempts to read the value. On all x86 Windows machines it is successful, and on Windows XP x64 and Windows 7 x64, but Windows Vista x64 is unable to locate the key. If I look in the registry, it doesn't actually write it to Wow6432Node on Windows Vista; it writes it to `Software\DroidExplorer\InstallPath`.

If I do not forcefully tell the installer to write to Wow6432Node, it writes the value to `Software\DroidExplorer\InstallPath`, but the bootstrapper still tries to look in Wow6432Node because of the [registry reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384235%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). This is on all x64 systems.

Why is Windows Vista x64 the only one I have this issue with? Is there a way around this?

**I just want to add an edit that this is still open. None of the suggestions below have yet to solve this issue.**

Comment: Do you have `Win64="no"` on your `<Component>` tag? If not, try setting it.

Comment: doesn't even let me compile if I set that... I was really hoping it was something that easy.

The error I get is:
error LGHT0204: ICE80: This 32BitComponent InstallDirectoryRegister uses 64BitDirectory INSTALLDIR

Comment: If you changed the component to be 32 bit, you must also change the install directory to be 32 bit. That's what the error message means.

Comment: The registry redirection/reflection was changed between Vista and 7 (I believe you can find the details about that on MSDN)

Comment: @Lex Li - The component is not 32 bit, the bootstrapper is. The component that is installed by the msi is 64 bit.

Comment: @Anders - According to MSDN, registry reflection was removed in 7, which just stopped the synchronization between the x86 and x64 hives, but the problem is that it works just fine on 7, and doesn't work on vista. x86 registry is still redirected to WOW6432Node on x64. So I dont understand why its not working on Vista

Comment: @Ryan Conrad I stumbled upon exactly this problem. I conclude that it's just a Windows quirk. I resorted to using a custom action to do my registries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that registry redirection is failing on Windows Vista x64 is very strange because according to MSDN, *[Registry Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232(VS.85).aspx)*, Windows Vista should also be affected by it.

A comment in another answer, "*This does not work, when I build the x64 version of the application, that installs in the x64 PFiles, it tells me that I am using a 64-bit install directory and doesn't allow the Win64=no*" left me a bit confused as to what type of MSIs you are building.

Registry redirection is only going to affect 32-bit components in your MSI. If the target platform for the WiX project is x86, then the resulting MSI is a 32-bit MSI and all components will be affected by registry redirection.

On the other hand, if the target platform of the WiX project is x64, then the only components that will be affected by the registry redirection will be those that are explicitly marked as Win64=no. (By default, WiX assumes that all components are 64-bit if your target platform is x64.)

Note that if the component for your registry entry is included inside the ProgramFiles64 folder, then WiX will assume that it is a 64-bit component, and it will not be affected by registry redirection. This is the reason WiX is not allowing you to specify Win64=no on that component.

You should verify that every component that contains a registry entry that you do want to be redirected is configured to use ProgramFiles (the 32-bit one) as it's the parent directory in both your x86 and your x64 MSI files.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have to change the code of your 32-bit bootstrapper. You should test whether the application run under 64-bit operation system, for example with respect of `IsWow64Process` function (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139.aspx). If the operation system is 64-bit then you should open key with `KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_WOW64_64KEY` flag (or other flags combined with `KEY_WOW64_64KEY`) in `RegOpenKeyEx`.

If you will receive close problems with file redirection under 64-bit operation systems you can call `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection` in the bootstrapper (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365743.aspx).

**UPDATED** based on the comment: If you want that `Software\WOW6432Node\DroidExplorer\InstallPath` key will be created by MSI (for example it you install a 32-bit application) you can do this directly. Of cause you should Windows Installer are running on 64-bit operation systems with conditions in the component table using `VersionNT64` property (or `Msix64` or `Intel64` if needed).

**UPDATED 2** consider usage of `msidbComponentAttributesDisableRegistryReflection` or /and `msidbComponentAttributes64bit` flags for components with registry keys which you create. Moreover verify which values you use in `Template Summary` (`x64;1033` or `Intel;1033`) and `Page Count Summary` property (must be 200 or greater) in the summary information stream.

Comment: the bootstrapper is not having the problem, it is looking in the right registry hive. its the msi that is writing the value to the wrong hive. on win7 64bit, the 32bit msi, some how writes to the 64bit hive, not the expected WOW6432Node like it should.

Comment: i meant vista 64bit in my comment, not win7, but anyhow. I know I can do it manually by forcing WOW6432Node, but I shouldn't have to force it, as it should write to there any how, since the installer is 32bit. why do i not have to force WOW6432Node on Win7?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. You can just define two components one with the registry key `Software\WOW6432Node\DroidExplorer\InstallPath` and another with the registry key `Software\DroidExplorer\InstallPath`. For the first component you should use the condition `VersionNT64` and for the second one the condition `NOT VersionNT64`. Your setup will create always the 32-bit version of the key `Software\DroidExplorer\InstallPath`.

Comment: I will try that, but currently Win7 64bit works fine. Its Vista 64 & XP 64 that don't. Will an x86 MSI have access to write to Software\WOW6432Node\DroidExplorer\InstallPath on a 64bit machine? I was under the impression that x86 does not know that WOW6432Node exists, it just writes to the registry and the OS handles the reference. This is how it works in Win7 any how.

Comment: I am not quite understand your doubt. A 64-bit application on 64-bit operation system work with real registry and with the real file system, so it can write in any parts of registry where permission allows es. Because Administrators has full access to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node then 64-bit application can do this like you can do this with the 64-bit regedit.exe. A 32-bit application on 64-bit operation system works in a virtual world, see and can write only in a subset of registry and file system if the application not explicitly with KEY_WOW64_64KEY flag require other.

Comment: The MSI writes to the 64 bit path, even if i specify the WOW6432Node. This is only on vista and xp 64 bit, it works fine on win7 64 bit.

Comment: What is the values of the properties VersionNT64 and Msix64 on vista and xp 64 bit? Do you started msiexec.exe with the detaied log (/l*v)?  Could you post a link where I can download the detaild logs (one from Windows 7 and one from Vista or XP 64) In the detaild log file you can see all standard MSI properties. MSI must create a registry key based on conditions of the corresponding components. Which version of Windows Installer you have on 64-bit vista and xp? Can you install on the computers the last version of Windows Installer and retry the results?

Comment: Do you define  `msidbComponentAttributes64bit` for component? Windows Installer 4.0 and higher supports VersionNT64 Property (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372497.aspx). Which version of Windows Installer is installed of the xp 64 bit where you have problems? Moreover look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367451.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367430.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372070.aspx and verify whether your MSI is marekd as `Intel` or `Intel,x64`. You can use orca.exe or other MSI editor to set your MSI as pure 32-bit MSI

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is through a custom action.

You would have to call RegOpenKeyEx and set 0x100 to the REGSAM samDesired parameter to force use of the 64 bit registry. See RegOpenKeyEx [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724897(VS.85).aspx).

You could not use the standard .NET Registry classes to do this. You will have to manually use [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) if using a .NET language.

You may be better off by providing two installers, one for 64 bit and one for 32 bit. This is how we have combatted the issue, as it is a lot less complicated.

Comment: I dont want to force the 64 bit registry, i want to use the 32 bit registry, no matter what version of the OS. I tell it the path is within WOW6432Node but it is still writing to the "non-WOW6432Node" path.

Comment: You are mislead in how the WoW6432Node works, you cannot specify it in the path to your registry key.  If you are running in a 32 bit process on a 64 bit machine, the registry automatically uses this path.  If you are writing from a 64 bit process on a 64 bit machine, it uses the standard key.  If you need to write to the 32 bit section from a 64 bit installer, put the registry key in it's own component and specify Win64="no", MAKE SURE WoW6432Node is NOT in your path.  If that doesn't work, you may have to compile everything for 32 bit.

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the component to [Win32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API), using the `Win64="No"` parameter. Otherwise MSI will use whatever system it is run on as the default (that is, x64 on such OS).

So for example:

```
<Component Id="C__mycomponent" Guid="MYGUID" Win64="No">
  <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="Software\DroidExplorer\InstallPath" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall" />
</Component>
```

Comment: This does not work, when i build the x64 version of the application, that installs in the x64 PFiles, it tells me that i am using a 64 bit install directory and doesnt allow the Win64=no

Comment: Sure, if you have an x64 component, then the whole msi is x64 and won't allow win32 components. It's not possible (without cheating) to have both win32 and x64 components in a single msi.
See here for the details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2008/01/15/different-packages-are-required-for-different-processor-architectures.aspx

Comment: That post says it should allow writing to both 64 and 32 bit hives, but thats the problem i am having, it doesn't write to the 32 bit hive if it is 64 bit install. I am even supplying WOW6432Node in the registry path.