# Can not disable Device Manager using a C++ program

Tags: c++, windows

I want to disable [Device Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager) from my control panel editing registry values. I can do it in C#, but I want to do it in C++ without using any .NET framework. I have succedded to change my processor name in C++. But I am facing a problem when I want to disable the task manager. Here is my code.

```
    HKEY hKey;

    RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                 "HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\CentralProcessor\\0",
                 0,
                 KEY_SET_VALUE,
                 &hKey);

    RegSetValueEx(hKey, REGNAME_TO_WRITE, 0, REG_SZ,
                  (const unsigned char *)"ProcessorNameString",
                  strlen("ProcessorNameString"));

    //RegCloseKey(hKey);

    // The problem begins here

     RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                  "Software\\Policies\\Microsoft\MMC\\{74246bfc-4c96-11d0-abef-0020af6b0b7a}\\",
                  0,
                  KEY_SET_VALUE,
                  &hKey );

    RegSetValueEx( hKey,"Restrict_Run",0,REG_SZ,
                   (const unsigned char *)"1",
                   strlen("1") );

    RegCloseKey(hKey);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What version of Windows?  What processor architecture?  Perhaps you are running 32-bit code and changing the 32-bit view (WOW64 redirected) of the registry, but Windows is looking in the 64-bit registry.

Comment: I am using windows 7 Professional edition 32 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viola, I got the solution. The solution would be like this:

```
DWORD dwVal = 1;

HKEY hKey = HKEY_CURRENT_USER;

RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\Policies\\Microsoft\\MMC\\{74246bfc-4c96-11d0-abef-0020af6b0b7a}\\", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);

RegSetValueEx (hKey, "Restrict_Run", 0, REG_DWORD, (LPBYTE)&dwVal, sizeof(DWORD));

RegCloseKey(hKey);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should disable WOW64 registry redirection, or else your program may make changes to WOW6432Node instead of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

See [Disabling registry redirection for a registry key on an x64 platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011554/disabling-registry-redirection-for-a-registry-key-on-x64-platform)

Comment: Thanks for answering but what about HKEY hKey;


    `RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                  "HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\CentralProcessor\\0",
                  0,
                  KEY_SET_VALUE,
                  &hKey );



    RegSetValueEx( hKey,REGNAME_TO_WRITE,0,REG_SZ,
                   (const unsigned char *)"ProcessorNameString",
                   strlen("ProcessorNameString") );`This portion of code does change my processors' name perfectly. What is the problem for rest of the code. I am using windows 7 professional edition.